# Laravel-5.5 Event-Listener not working

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-5.5

I want to create rows in `carts` table for new users When they registered. For this reason, I created `UserRegistered` (event) and `CreateNewCart`(listener) classes.

I read docs and watch some youtube videos then I tried what they did. But didin't work for me..

**Event**;
public $user;

```
public function __construct(User $user)
{
   $this->user = $user;
}
```

**Listener**;

```
public function handle(RegisteredUser $event)
{
   Cart::insert
    ([
       'user_id' => $event->user->id
    ]);
}
```

**User Model;**

```
protected $events = [
   'created' => Events\RegisteredUser::class
 ];
```

Where do I mistake and How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 5.5 you need to use [`$dispatchesEvents`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events) property instead of `$events`:

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'created' => Events\RegisteredUser::class
];
```

Also, make sure, [you've registered the event and listener](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/events#registering-events-and-listeners).

Comment: it works.. I haven't seen $dispatchesEvents in "events" docs, so I didin't know that. Thanks for your answer. and happy new year :)

Comment: Happy new year to you too. )